# Unable to add LUIS app to a new dispatch model

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS app that I have assigned an Azure LUIS resource to in LUIS. So I have my Starter_Key and Azure resource on the app. What I want to do is create a new dispatch model I can use in a Bot Framework Bot.

So to do this I start to run the following commands to create a new dispatch file:

`dispatch init -name <Name for dispatch> --luisAuthoringKey <From my Azure Luis resource> --luisAuthoringRegion westeurope`

I'm running into an issue when I try to add my luis app to this dispatch

`dispatch add -type luis -id <My LUIS app Id> -name <My LUIS app name> -key <From my Azure Luis resource>`

The error I get back is:

`Can't find LUIS app <My LUIS app name> with authoring key <From my Azure Luis resource> and region westeurope`

I have had a look through the [dispatch docs](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#adding-source-to-dispatch) and [Microsoft Luis Authoring keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys) and but can't see what the issue might be.

If I run the dispatch command with my Starter_Key value I am able to add it so I think it is to do with the link between Azure and Luis. Interestingly If I go to LUIS > User> Settings and try to add an Azure resource here, it doesn't add it even though I have created a new one through here. It looks like a bug with LUIS but I might be wrong.

I'd appreciate any help or guidance with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mike. There have been some LUIS *hiccups* this weekend. Can  you try this again this morning, and let me know if you're still experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I have just retried but I'm still getting the same result, I'm not able to add it to my dispatch :(

Do you think it is something wrong in the process I'm using?